# mysql - strange schema behavior in MySQL Admin

Tags: mysql, schema, mysqladministrator

I am running several schemas on a single mysql server. One of the schemas has an underscore in its name ("some_name"), and the rest don't. I noticed that in the Admin GUI I am seeing 2 schemas that represent the same one, with one having an escape character before the underscore - so in the schema list I see:

- schema1
- schema2
- some_name
- **some\_name**
- schema3
- ....

I have no idea how it gets there, and though I tried to, I cannot remove/drop it because it **doesn't** show up when running mysql from the console. The problem arises when I have to grant users permission on **both** schemas to enable them to access and manipulate data on either. This is really messed up and I am looking to understand how/why this happens and how this could be avoided (other than renaming the schema to remove the underscore). thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your datadir folder.  Any folder/director in your datadir will show up as a database on MySQL even if it is not really a database.  I often encounter 'backup' database because we use that folder as backup.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```